# fixed proxy in vite.config.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I have a project with React and in order to avoid CROS palicy error in the package.json file of the project, I set the proxy and I have no problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHleY.png)

But now I uploaded the project with Vite and I saw in the Docs section that I need to add api one by one  I should write them and specify a target for them to prevent Cros error, but my project is big and has more than 150 APIs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6IRk.png)

My question is, is it possible to put a proxy in the Vitejs project like the React project?
Or should I write the api one by one and specify the target for it

I didn't get the result I wanted by searching, and I also used Chat GPT, but I still didn't get the result

Please look at the uploaded photos.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.